# Moq, the types between Setup() and Returns() doesn't match

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, moq

I have an interface:

```
public interface IPeopleService
{
    Task<List<Person>> GetPeople();
}
```

Here is my code to mock up the return for the request:

```
List<Person> people = ...;
var mockPeopleService = new Mock<IPeopleService>();
 mockPeopleService.Setup(ps => ps.GetPeople()).Returns<Task<List<Person>>>(Task.FromResult(people));
```

Error persists no matter what I have done.....

[image]

After trying to use ReturnsAsync() it shows me this error:

```
mockPeopleService.Setup(ps => ps.GetPeople()).ReturnsAsync(people);
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

[image]

Comment: Just drop the type parameter `mockPeopleService.Setup(ps => ps.GetPeople()).Returns(Task.FromResult(people));`

Comment: thanks @Jasen, I have tried it and it works. But I don't why it didn't work with the type parameter. Could you please explain? thanks

Comment: As pointed out in Johnny's answer, the type specification causes the compiler to match a different method overload and your input parameters do not match the expected method signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are using this method:

```
IReturnsResult<TMock> Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult> valueFunction);
```

In your example it doesn't make sense to use that overload. Just drop `T`. Also might be usefull to use `ReturnsAsync`.

```
mockPeopleService.Setup(ps => ps.GetPeople()).ReturnsAsync(people);
```

Comment: hi Johnny, please see my updated part in the question. thanks

Comment: @Franva which version of moq are you using? 4.2.1312.1319 (2013-12-13) this is when it was added... If it doesn't work for you you could use `Returns(Task.FromResult(people))` it is essentially the same.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I'm using version Moq 4.10.1. I tried to use Task.FromResult(people), but it throws me error. Please see my update 2.

Comment: @Franva seems people itself is `Task<List<People>>` instead of just `List<People>`